# I need to display a variant image on a radio button variant selector, but can't seem to find how to properly pull the variant img src. Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-template

So I'm on Shopify product template (using Debut Theme). I changed the default dropdown variant selector to radio buttons and it works great. I wanted the radio buttons to display the variant image, and that's where I'm stuck. (Here's a link to a test product where I want this to work: [TEST product link](https://coolpebbles.com/collections/shop/products/copy-of-terrario-ufo?variant=39331488104471)

Here's the radio button form:

```html
{% form 'product', product, class:form_classes %}


 

{% unless product.has_only_default_variant %}
              {% for option in product.options_with_values %}
                <label style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.2em;"{% if option.name == 'default' %}class="label--hidden" {% endif %}for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                 ¡Escoge la versión que quieres!
                </label>
                {% assign option_position = forloop.index %}
                <fieldset class="botones-radio">
                  {%- for value in option.values -%}
                  <div class="imagen-mas-boton">
                     <input type="radio" class="single-option-selector-{{ section.id }} "
                        {% if option.selected_value == value %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
                        value="{{ value | escape }}"
                        data-index="option{{option_position}}"
                        name="{{ option.name | handleize }}"
                        id="SingleOptionSelector-{{option_position}}">
                       
                       
                       
                        <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '200x' }}" />
               
                   
                      <label style="text-align: center;" for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}">
                        {{value}} 
                      </label>
                  
                    </div>
                  {%- endfor -%}
                </fieldset>
              {% endfor %}
            {% endunless %}


            <select name="id" id="ProductSelect-{{ section.id }}" class="product-form__variants no-js">
              {% for variant in product.variants %}
                {% if variant.available %}
                  <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} value="{{ variant.id }}">
                    {{ variant.title }}
                  </option>
                {% else %}
                  <option disabled="disabled">{{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</option>
                {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            {% if section.settings.show_quantity_selector %}
              <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--quantity">
                <label for="Quantity">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
                <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="product-form__input" pattern="[0-9]*">
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          <div class="product-form__item product-form__item--submit{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} product-form__item--payment-button{% endif %}{% if product.has_only_default_variant %} product-form__item--no-variants{% endif %}">
            {% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %}
              {{ form | payment_button }}
              {% endif %}
              <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart-{{ section.id }}" {% unless current_variant.available %}disabled="disabled"{% endunless %} class="btn product-form__cart-submit{% if section.settings.enable_payment_button %} btn--secondary-accent{% endif %}">
               
                <span id="AddToCartText-{{ section.id }}">
                  {% unless current_variant.available %}
                    {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
                  {% else %}
                    {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
                  {% endunless %}
                </span>
                </button>
            </div>
          {% endform %}
```

Now, the `<img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '200x' }}" />` obviously displays the featured image so both variants will display the same image, and both will change when selecting the other variant and refreshing the page.

I want to display the image assigned to each variant. I tried `<img src="{{ variant| img_url: '200x' }}" />` and `<img src="{{ variant.image | img_url: '200x' }}" />`

But it doesn't seem to work.

I also would like to display each variants price on the lable, for this I tried the following:

`<label style="text-align: center;" for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}"> {{value}} {{current_variant.price | money }} </label>`

but this will show the price of the selected variant and will only change when refreshed.

Comment: You're adding the variants inside the options for loop. That's why you're not able to get the variant image. Change options for loop to varianst for loop.

Comment: @HymnZzy I'm not very clear on how to do that, and keep the option selector working. I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between option and variant. Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: A variant (ex: Red Color - Small Size) is a combination for options (ex: Color, Size). So, practically, if you have only one option (say Color) a variant and option are the same, but technically variant is made up of different options.

Comment: So to change  the for loop I have to change ´for="SingleOptionSelector-{{ forloop.index0 }}´

to ´for="currentVariant-{{ forloop.index0 }}´

Then how would I display the image? I tried:

 <img src="{{ variant.featured_image | img_url: '200x' }}" />

and 

 <img src="{{ variant.image | img_url: '200x' }}" />